# Binomial GLM post-hoc tests for unequal sample sizes

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, generalized-linear-model, post-hoc

I have a set of data that are binomial, and am comparing them across 9 years. The first 5 years have low sample sizes ($~n=20$) and the last 4 have $n>100$. I've run a glm in R with the family set to "binomial", and the results look reasonable.

However, when I did the multiple comparisons afterwards using the [multcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html) package, as shown below

```
cs_comp<-glht(model2, linfct =  mcp(bin_Year= "Tukey"))
```

I got some really unexpected results that do not coincide with a bar graph I made of the means $\pm$ SE (essentially, years that were not significantly different from each other that I'd expect to be AND years that were significantly different that I didn't expect to be). I've been told that this is likely due to the unequal sample sizes; of the 9 years of data I have, the last 4 years have 100+ data points, while the first 5 years have 20-25 data points.

I've also had the suggestion that I use Wald's CIs to determine pairwise comparisons by looking for overlapping CI's. Does anyone know if this is a better approach to unequal samples sizes of this magnitude, or if there is another (even better) multiple comparison method for this? If so, any tips on how to approach it in R? I have figured out how to make confidence intervals in R, but not Wald's.

EDIT: I've found somewhere that one can use `confint.default(model)` to obtain Wald's 95% CI's, however, this results in completely different numbers than were provided to me by a friend in a software program I don't have access to (and can't remember what it is). The reason I'm searching now for this is the CI's that he obtained when running this data set for me are only to 2 decimal places, and I need more to determine if there is true overlap. Furthermore, if I've obtained CI's from the `'confint.default()` code that are negative or higher than 1, I'm almost certain they cannot be correct, since I have a binomial data set with only 0's and 1's...

Comment: What were your "unexpected results" and did you do ${9 \choose 2} = 36$ pairwise comparisons? I would not be surprised by non-significant differences if so. You can model the effects of year in the binomial glm, e.g., if you wanted to just test for linear (or quadratic or whatever) components. It would be helpful if you indicated why you wanted multiple comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks @lockedoff. I would expect that yes, I did that many pairwise comparisons (I assume that's how the code works), however my data from the last 2 years graphically show such a dramatic decrease in clutch size, so I anticipated being able to see this statistically as well, but the 2006 data showed no difference when graphically, it should have the most! I wanted all the multiple comparisons to make sure I wasn't overlooking any other less-obvious differences in the clutch sizes. Here's a link to a jpg of the graph: [bit.ly/eJV2fK]. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your code for `model2`? I'm not familiar with your field, but I'm wondering why the binomial distribution is appropriate for clutch size (= number of eggs laid in one egg-laying period -- right?), instead of Poisson.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that part @lockedoff: this species only lays 1 or 2 eggs, so the poisson model wasn't working. I converted by 1-egg nests to 0s and the 2-egg nests to 1s. Here the code I used:

`model2<-glm(bin_clutchsize~bin_Year,binomial)`

(Thanks @chi, for solving my account problem!)

Comment: I'm not sure that the (almost three thousand) people who've come across this page in their search for help have learned much from it. It seems unlikely that anybody can usefully answer the question without added information from the OP, especially regarding why there is a mismatch with the "completely different numbers" that "were provided to me by a friend in a software program I don't have access to (and can't remember what it is)"